# onclick jquery function not working in wordpress header file

Tags: jquery, javascript

I am trying to get alert on click event of a tag, but it seems to be not working. Here is the code.
I put this in header.php

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {

  jQuery('.neha').click(function () {
 var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
        alert(addressValue );
  })

});
</script>
```

and HTML code is

```
<a class="neha" href="ID-1">neha</a>
```

I added this but nothing is appear.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean nothing appears? You probably get redirected to other page (or 404 page). Try to prevent that, using function preventDefault, like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/dzonit/jck9cbnr/

Comment: Hey thanks.But the code is not working when I insert it into the wordpress header.php